# Using jquery to get a partial view and updating the UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview, url.action

I need to render a partial view (returned from the controller) to show some customer summary details. This will need to happen when the user clicks on a button. In the the mean time the user can select different customers on a grid. I keep note of the selected customer id in a hidden field using jquery on the grids selection changed event. When the user clicks on a button i need to pass this hidden field value (selected id) to the controller, the controller does some work and returns a partial view. I then need to render this partial view on the page. I have tried the following but have two problems

1. I cant fig out how to send the hidden field value to the controller
2. After the partial view is rendered I cant get it to rerender if the user selects another customer and clicks the button again

The code:

```
  #PlaceHolder is just a div element

function DoSomwWork() {
                $('#PlaceHolder')
                .load('<%= Url.Action("GetSelectedCustSummary", 
                                      "SomeController", 
                                       new { selectedId = **HIDDEN FIELD VAL HERE** })%>');
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to post a little bit more code/explain things in a bit more detail for anyone to help you...

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will be able to do it this way.

However since you are already using MVC, you shall be able to define a action ("GetSelectedCustSummary"in your case) and return a json object instead, then manipulate it with your jQuery

Update:
Define Action Method something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ActionName(string id)
{
    //some logic here to get QueryResult
    return Json(QueryResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

then call your Action Method in Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    //you can assign id dynamically
    url: '<%= Url.Content("~/Controller/ActionName/YourId") %>',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
       //manipulate your div content with data
    },
    error: function (e) {
        //manipulate your div content with error
    }
});
```

Every time you click update button, assign the id you want, and trigger the Jquery function.
It worked for me in my project

Comment: Thanks for the replies. But I am not sure how your solution will work. Just to sum up my problem all I want to achive is to display some customer summary information on the same page when the user clicks on a button. The customer details will be based on the current selected customer id on the telerik grid. This Id will need to be passed to the controller to do some work and then the controller will need to return ther result (partial view i would have hope) which I will then render on the same page